# V4.Fragments после удаления,инициализируется не правильно

Tags: android, android-fragment, xamarin

Я использую **V4.Fragments**.Для создания фрагмента,делаю вот это :

```
            MyFragment = new CustomFragment();

            var Transaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

            Transaction.Add(Resource.Id.FrameContainer,MyFragment, "CustomFrg");
            Transaction.Commit();
```

Затем мне необходимо удалить этот **фрагмент**,для того чтобы освободить занимаемое им место

```
  var trans = Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                                        Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment frg =  Activity.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("CustomFrg") as CustomFragment;
                                        //GC.Collect();
                                        trans.Remove(frg);
                                        ((MainActivity)Activity).OpenCamera_Click(s1,e1);
                                        trans.Commit();
```

Работает нормально, только когда я пытаюсь пересоздать его, то почему то Activity(FragmentActivity) не инициализирован (т.е. Null) и я не могу понять,с чем это связанно?

Comment: это связано с жизненным циклом фрагментов, который описан в оф. документации. Не во все времена жизни фрагмента он прикреплен к активити

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решение как оказалось,не особо сложным. В моем варианте,я создал глобальную переменную **Listener** и использую устаревший метод **OnAttach()**

```
[Obsolete ("deprecated")]
        public override void OnAttach(Android.App.Activity activity)
        {
            base.OnAttach(activity);
            this.Listener = (MainActivity)activity;
        }
```

Делаем каст на наш **MainActivity** и все работает.

Comment: Это не решение :) Это прямая дорога к OutOfMemoryError :)

Comment: почему? С чем это связанно?

Comment: потому что тогда в `OnDetach` нужно обнулять ссылку на активити, иначе могут быть утечки памяти. А если так делать, мы снова у первоначальной проблемы.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja так у меня метод OnAttach,а не Детач ))

Comment: Они должны в паре использоваться, чтобы знать что фрагмент уже отключен и активити уже может не существовать.

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю, первый код исполнятся в контексте активити.
Второй в контексте самого фрагмента. Как только вы его удалили, `Activity` становится `null`.
Вообще манипулировать фрагментами лучше всегда в контексте активити, тогда избежите подобных ошибок.

Comment: не совсем так. Код "удаления" исполняется в самом фрагменте,затем код"инициалиазации" происходит опять в самой Активити(т.е. изначально,инициализация тоже осуществляется в Активити).
Я нашел для себя решение,еще немного проэксперементирую и выложу ответ. 
Есть другой вопрос,что лучше использовать для освобождения(уничтожения) фрагмента из памяти?(и всего контекста,со всем вытекающим,типа члены(переменные\контролы\битмапы) \ методы класс,так вот Replace или Remove?!

Comment: С точки зрения освобождения памяти нет разницы между Replace и Remove. Главное смотреть чтобы не осталось ссылок на фрагмент в коде.

Comment: не совсем понял про "ссылки на фрагмент в коде"

Comment: Любые переменные со ссылкой на фрагмент

Comment: у меня сейчас появилась другая проблема.
 Фрагмент уничтожаю,создаю новый(такой же. уничтожение и новая инициализация происходит в самом фрагменте). Суть в том,что в моем методе OnCreateView есть ссылки на кнопки от самой Активити. 
На выходе получается следующая картина: сколько раз я создал фрагмент(после удаления) ,то столько раз он зайдет в методы кнопок(т.е. если я создал 3 фрагмента,то в случае нажатия на кнопку "от Активити" в последний момент(относительно 3ех созданных), система зайдет 3 раза в метод. Что это за бред?! Такое ощущение будто фрагменты не удаляются  и где то плетутся.

Comment: я кстати пробовал делать это в контексте Активити,все равно результат тот же. С Чем это связанно!?

Comment: Почитайте какой-нить туториал по фрагментам. У Вас с этим путаница. Фрагмент и активити должны быть полностью автономны, никаких передач UI элементов туда-обратно, иначе получите утечки памяти. Если им надо общаться, то только через интерфейс, и опять же этот интерфейс должен быть абсолютно абстрактный от элементов UI.

Comment: да я смотрел туториалы. Дело в том что я юзаю ActionToolbar,и во фрагменте я использую кнопки с тулбара. (именно мои контролы,а не меню). Тут не идет передача UI,а "использование" контролов Активити из фрагмента.Я не передаю никакие экземпляры,работаю через свойство (getters),которое ссылается на проинициализированные кнопки в самой Активити и все :)

Comment: Создайте новый вопрос с кодом, посмотрим.

Comment: окей,создам. Благодарю за внимание,плюсану твой ответ :)

Comment: Отлично :) И ссылку тут оставьте, плиз.

Comment: только сильно не пугайся,я пишу на C# Xamarin,все тоже самое. Можешь попробовать заимплементить в нативной форме. Спасибо !
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465094/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5