# Пересоздание фрагментов, влечет за собой странное поведение

Tags: android, android-fragment, xamarin

Я использую **V4.Fragment**,проблема заключается в том,что в сам фрагмент я должен удалять(для освобождения занятых им ресурсов) и снова пересоздавать(некая итерация,которая может повторяться N - кол-во раз).
Помимо всего,у меня есть мой **ActionBar**(appcompat v7),в который я добавил свои контролы(в виде кнопок).
Проблема заключается в том,что при удалении(скорее всего я не корректно это делаю),складывается впечатление,что эти удаленные фрагменты плетутся где то хвоством и возникает следующая аномалия:

> Сколько раз я создал тот самый фрагмент(заново проинилизировал после
>   удаления), то столько ***раз*** и будет запущен метод кнопки из
>   тулбара(а именно кнопки Активити)

Мой метод **OnCreate()**

```
 //не нарушаем ООП,допустим только для чтения
 public Button _MyBtn { get { return MyBtn; } }
//кнопа из тулбара,как пример
  Button MyBtn;

      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
         base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        MyBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnToolbar);
       //другие контролы,не столь так важно
     //ETC ......
     }
```

Далее вызываю АПИ камеры и в соответствии с положительным результатом, я делаю следующее:

```
  protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
             //все ок,значит создаем фрагмент
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok && requestCode == (int)Codes.CameraFromActivity)
            {

                    //создаем наш фрагмент
                    NewFragment = new MyCustomFragment();
                    var Transaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

                   Transaction.Add(Resource.Id.FrameContainer, NewFragment, "NewFragment");
                   Transaction.AddToBackStack(null);

                    Transaction.Commit();

            }
```

А так выглядит участок кода во фрагменте:

```
FragmentActivity Listener;

[Obsolete ("deprecated")]
public override void OnAttach(Android.App.Activity activity)
{
    base.OnAttach(activity);
    this.Listener = (MainActivity)activity;
}

public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View _View = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomFragment, container, false);
    //инициализация контролов  

    //та самая кнопка из Активити,метод которой будет выполняться столько раз,сколько раз я заново проиницилизровал новые фрагменты.
    //т.е. 3 раза создал фрагмент(которые до этого были удалены),то тогда 3 раза зайдет в метод.
    ((MainActivity)Listener).MyBtn.Touch += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //метод кнопки
        }
}
```

А вот и метод,через который я удаляю\создаю фрагмент:

//данный метод пробовал суть как в контекст Активити,так и в самом фрагменте,результат тот же  :

```
 public void GalleryFragment ()
    {
       MyCustomFragment  frg = new MyCustomFragment();
        var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        // Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment Old = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("NewFragment");
        // trans.Remove(Old);
        trans.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_in, Resource.Animation.slide_out);

        trans.Replace(Resource.Id.FrameContainer, frg, "NewFragment");
        trans.AddToBackStack(null);

        trans.Commit();

    }
```

Что я делаю не так? Нормальное ли это поведение фрагмента?

Comment: А почему так важно иметь обработчик нажатия на кнопку именно во фрагменте? Если его перенести в активити, все вопросы снимутся.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja это получится морока,т.к. я работаю с битмапом,которые инициализированы в контексте фрагмента...вот тут да,будут такие капитальные MEMORY LEAKS :)). 
Да получиться шило на мило,разве нет?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja в общем ты оказался прав,относительно того,чтобы пихнуть все в активити. Я конечно кое что подправил еще,но не суть. Можешь изменить свой ответ и я помечу как "солюшн". Кстати плюсани мои вопросы,это все равно бесплатно!) Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое верное решение с точки зрения архитектуры Андроид это переработать логику работы приложения и перенести обработчик `MyBtn.Touch` в код активити.

Comment: Работает!
Теперь твой черед)

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение (но не самое верное с точки зрения архитектуры Android)
Обработку нажатия на кнопку вынести в делегат фрагмента, назовем его `OnTouchDelegate`, затем во фрагменте перекрыть эти 2 метода жизненного цикла

```
public override void OnAttach(Android.App.Activity activity)
{
    base.OnAttach(activity);
    ((MainActivity)activity).MyBtn.Touch += OnTouchDelegate;
}

public override void OnDeattach(Android.App.Activity activity)
{        
    ((MainActivity)activity).MyBtn.Touch -= OnTouchDelegate;
    base.OnDeattach(activity);
}
```

Как-то так, давно не писал на C#, но общая идея, думаю ясна.

Comment: попробовал,не помогло...
Так поробовал Листенеру дать NULL в OnDetach'e  и все равно,та же херня. Как то эти фрагменты не правильно удаляются...Как их полностью удалить? Есть идеи?

Comment: ты не пробовал быстро заимплементить мой случай в нативной форме?
Какое там поведение..интересно)